# Measuring execution time of functions and call count in linux module

Tags: linux, profiling, kernel-module

I am maintaining a kernel module on linux 2.6.18 (RHEL 5.5) kernel and we are seeing some performance issues.

I am trying to use oprofile for general profiling but it does not provide (or I do not know the option) statistics regarding how many times a function was called or how much time it took to execute a particular function. I can write my own code for measuring time taken in executing each function but it would be difficult to insert this into each function.

Is there a profiler that can accomplish this?

Comment: Try perf instead, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229336/linux-application-profiling/2229834#2229834

Comment: Is `perf` available for 2.6.18 kernel?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's in 2.6.31 onwards. Maybe you can run your module under the latest kernel version, perf it, analyze the results and backport the needed modification? It's a bit of a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

Try also using the latest [flamegraphs](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph).