# Socket select() Time Switching?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcpsocket

I have created 6 Sockets and simultaneously listening to all of them using select. I want to find out how much time does the CPU take  switching from 1 socket to another. Does anyone know; if not can someone guide me please on how to compute this problem!

Comment: What do you mean by "switching from 1 socket to another"? The `select` function doesn't "switch" between sockets, it checks which socket received activity, and from your point of view it could be said that the kernel checks all sockets simultaneously.

Comment: What have you tried to do already? Have you used the standard Linux profiling tools?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229336/linux-application-profiling

Comment: I was under the notion that if my 1_socket receives 6 bytes of data and  my 2_socket also receives 6 bytes of data, it will first resolve on 1_socket then switch onto 2_socket!!!

Comment: What is 'it'? What do you mean by 'resolve'? And 'switch'?

Comment: The `select` function can return with multiple sockets active in the sets. So both `1_socket` and `2_socket` (as per your example) may be in e.g. the read set when `select` returns. There simply is no "switching".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood what the select call is actually doing, the man page for select says the following:

> Three  independent  sets of file descriptors are watched.  Those
>   listed in readfds will be watched to see if characters  become 
>   available  for reading  (more  precisely, to see if a read will not
>   block; in particu- lar, a file descriptor is also ready on
>   end-of-file), those in writefds will  be  watched  to  see  if  a 
>   write  will  not block, and those in exceptfds will be watched for
>   exceptions.  **On exit, the sets are  modified  in place to indicate
>   which file descriptors actually changed status**.  Each of the three
>   file descriptor sets may be specified  as  NULL if no file descriptors
>   are to be watched for the corresponding class of events.

So when your call to select returns what it will tell you is which, if any, of the file descriptors are (in your case) ready to be read from.  It's then up to you to decide which to read and how to read it.

If you can I'd reccomend tracking down a copy of Unix Network Programming (by Stevens, Fenner, Rudoff).  This will give you all the background information and example C code that you will ever want on network programming.

Or look at the tutorial [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?2%20select_tut)